# Linux: Are there any Desktop Widget engines that runs html/css/javascript?

Tags: linux, desktop, html, javascript, widgets

I'm looking for a Desktop widget engine for linux that lets me program widgets using html, css, and javascript

Any suggestions?

Also comment if you have win/osx tips :)

Comment: Are you using Gnome, KDE, enlightenment?

Comment: @furtelwart: Does that matter if he asks for _any_ widget engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i could have done a better search job in the first place, this is what i was looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_widget_engines

Answer (score 2):

Plasma that is part of KDE uses WebKit to run widgets. OS X also uses WebKit for it's widgets so some of the OS X widgets works as well.